# Eclipse Error - "Could Not Find Or Load Main Class"

Tags: java, eclipse

I started using Eclipse today to develop my java programs (did not move/touch any settings).

I try to run the Java programs, and I get this message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class CLASSNAME
```

This happens for ALL my java programs, including those I developed before (and ran without problems on Eclipse). However, this was not the case yesterday; I was able to run developed programs without problem.

I did not uninstall/change my Java installation. The developed programs run without problem when I use another IDE to run it...

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Once please check the error messages if any in the Problems view

Answer (score 1):

i think their is a problem in your CLASSPATH variable. use echo %CLASSPATH%, the first entry in it should be (.)

Answer (score 1):

Clean and build the project will work, if not try the same thing for work space.

Soman.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem one of the jar files was missing which i removed in the configure build path it started working fine for me.